# Prepend string before each line of stdin

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, pipe, stdout

I have this script which sends logs from each Kubernetes pod to stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;

oc project cdt-dev

pods=$(oc get pods --show-all=false -o name)

for j in ${pods}; do
    oc logs -f "$j" | bunyan -o short -l error &
done

wait;
```

what I want to do is prepend the logs with the pod name, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# ...

for j in ${pods}; do
    oc logs -f "$j" | bunyan -o short -l error |  echo "$j => $stdin" &
done

wait
```

I think you can see what I am trying to do, I pipe the logs through a program called bunyan which interprets the logs and then I want to prepend the name of the pod ($j) to each line. But the above can't be right. Is there a way to do this with plain old bash?

Note $stdin is just some dummy variable representing a single line of stdin, that doesn't really exist here tmk.

Answer (score 5):

One option is `awk`:

```
for j in ...; do
  oc ... | bunyan --color ... | awk -v node="$j" '{print node " " $0}'
done
```

An example run:

```
$ for j in node1 node2 node3
> do
> echo stuff | awk -v node="$j" '{print node " " $0}'
> done
node1 stuff
node2 stuff
node3 stuff
```

Another option is `sed`:

```
for j in node1 node2 node3; do
  j=${j////\\/}
  j=${j//&/\\&}
  oc ... | bunyan --color ... | sed "s/^/$j /"
done
```

We take care to escape any forward-slashes or `&` in `j`, as sed interprets those specially in `s//` commands. I've used a bash-ism there to do search-and-replace in the parameter expansion. The two forward-slashes mean "replace all of the matches" and the doubled `\\` are there in order to result in a single backslash in the replaced text.

Comment: thanks, I have a solution which I posted, but it doesn't keep the control chars, so I lose the terminal colors/styling which was helpful, any idea how to keep the control chars etc? I will try your solution right now.

Comment: your solution works well, but it has the same problem as mine - control chars are gone / terminal styling is gone in the final output

Comment: It’s possible that bunyan checks to see if it’s writing to a terminal or not.

Comment: thanks you're right, I wonder who it determines that? anyway, I think @meuh solved that one for me, as a comment to my answer, you can force bunyan to use colors, with the --colors flag.

Comment: I incorporated the `--color` comment from meuh, @AlexanderMills, and also added a `sed` option.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
oc logs -f "$j" | bunyan -o short -l error  | while read line; do echo "$j $line"; done &
```

but one problem is that I lose the terminal styling, which was helpful.
Anyone know how to keep control chars etc?

Comment: `bunyan` has an option `--color` that might force colouring.

Comment: yeah good idea, that might be the one